# How many steals runner do when accessing multiple agendas in the archives?

Tags: android-netrunner

The runner accesses cards in archives and there are 3 agendas in it. The corp's identity is the "Argus Security" (whenever the runner steals an agenda, he or she must either take 1 tag or suffer 2 meat damage). How many times the id's ability triggered? One or three?

[image]

Comment: The runner must steal all agendas they can when accessing. They can't steal an agenda if they don't pay the cost (due to say Obokata or Red Herrings) or if a condition makes them unable to steal (Haarpsichord Studios), and each card accessed is accessed independently, so if you can steal all three, you access each agenda one at a time, steal, trigger Argus, then move to the next one, taking any combination of 3 tags or 6 meat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argus gets triggered 3 times. 
From the rulebook (page 18):

> **Archives**: The Runner accesses all cards in Archives and any
>   upgrades in its root. The Runner turns all cards faceup when
>   accessing them, and does not need to keep them in order. The
>   Runner steals all agendas in Archives and cannot trash cards
>   that are already in Archives. After accessing Archives, all
>   cards in Archives return to Archives faceup
>
> **Accessing Multiple Cards**
>   When accessing multiple cards, the Runner accesses them one
>   at a time in any order he likes.[...]
>
> The Runner must fully resolve his access to a card (steal it, pay
>   to trash it, etc.) before accessing the next card. If the Runner
>   scores an agenda that gives him seven or more points, he
>   immediately wins the game, even if he would otherwise access
>   more cards.

To summarise: runner accesses all cards in archives. Runner must steal all agendas they access. Runner accesses each card separately and fully resolves each access before continuing to the next card, so Argus ID gets triggered on each steal separately.

Comment: Yes, and it's worth being clear that the ID ability on Argus is worded "Whenever the Runner steals and agenda," which means each and every instance of an agenda being stolen. So, in the asked about example, the ability triggers three separate times upon that single Archives access. (Many abilities in Netrunner say "The first time each turn," but not the case here.)

Comment: @user30903 As I understand, the point of the question was: is it 3 separate steals or a single "steal them all" bundle, because latter will trigger "Whenever X happens" only once. That is the case with The Cleaners + Scorched Earth = only 1 additional meat damage.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your answer, just acknowledging that the OP asked specifically about how many times Argus triggers. I think it's worth clarifying that the wording on Argus means each instance of stealing, and doesn't count the entire access as a single trigger.